# Can an iPhone app receive an audio file with out the user opening the app?

Tags: iphone

I want to build a mobile app that has the ability to receive an audio file and then play said audio at a time previously set by the user. Does anybody know if it is possible on the iPhone to build such a function or is there no way around the user having to run the app and accept the audio file manually?.

Answer (score 1):

For your own use, you might be able to build a VOIP and streaming audio app that would run in the background while maintaining a network connection and continually playing silence (until it got the file and/or it was time to mix audio with the silence).  However, it is unlikely that such an app would comply with all SDK/App store rules.